# Gridview TemplateField Button: How to disable based on value?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

So I have this gridview, inside the gridview I have this template field, and inside this template fied I have this button.  Which all works really well.  However I would like to disable the button if the value of another column is something specific, please observe:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="grv_regionManagement" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commands" ShowHeader="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false" runat="server"
                        ID="btEdit" Enabled='<%# Eval("regionName") != "Disabled" %>' />&nbsp;
                </ItemTemplate>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Notice the evaluation:  Enabled='<%# Eval("regionName") != "Disabled" %>' , however this does not work and the button is always enabled, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%# Eval("regionName").ToString() != "Disabled" %>' />
```

Comment: Of course I will mark it as accepted, I had to wait 10 min after question creation to do so though :p

Comment: LOL, you may call me NeedyKenny!-)

Comment: Thx for this bro!